# Control Fan Speed Command Line

Tags: command-line, 13.04

After running `service kmod start` I get this error:

```
Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.77" (uid=1000 pid=2871 comm="start kmod ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

Does anyone know what this means and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try: `sudo service kmod start` ..